# SQLite Encoding Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, utf-8

I am trying to read UTF8 encoded text from a SQLite database using the following code. However, the code will occasionally throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. This appears to be due to the `sqlite3_column_bytes16` method call. If I replace the method call with a small number, such as 20, the exception is not thrown at all. What should I do to prevent this exception?

```
const unichar *text = sqlite3_column_text16(compiledStatement, 0);

if (text) {

   article = [NSString stringWithCharacters:text length:sqlite3_column_bytes16(compiledStatement, 0)];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3_column_text16()` return the number of *bytes* in the string, but
 `stringWithCharacters:length:` expects the number of *characters* as the second
argument:

```
const unichar *text = sqlite3_column_text16(compiledStatement, 0);
if (text) {
   NSUInteger length = sqlite3_column_bytes16(compiledStatement, 0)/sizeof(unichar);
   article = [NSString stringWithCharacters:text length:length];
}
```

This error could go unnoticed in some cases because the string returned by 
`sqlite3_column_bytes16()` is always zero-terminated, but your code would read beyond the
allocated buffer size and cause undefined behaviour.